# Difficulty with template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, stack

Okay, guys i have been trying to define a Stack  , each node also being of template type  but i get dozen different types of errors when the prog tries to compile. i will paste the program which uses a char-type stack and tries to pop letter 'e'

```
 #ifndef STACK_LIST_H
#define STACK_LIST_H
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Stack {
public:
    T pop();
    void push(T x);
    T isEmpty();
    T top();

private:
    int      size;
    Node<T> *   headNode;
    Node<T> *   currentNode;


};

#endif
```

Now the function definitions:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "Stack_list.h"

using namespace std;
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(){
    T x = headNode->get();
    Node<T>* p = new Node<T>::Node();
    p = headNode;
    headNode = headNode->getNext();
    delete p;
    return x; }

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T x){
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>::Node();
    newNode->setNext(headNode);
    newNode->set(x);
    headNode=newNode;
}

template <class T>
int Stack<T>::isEmpty(){
return (headNode ==NULL);}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::top(){
return headNode->get();
}
```

now the template class node:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

using namespace std;

/* The Node class */
template <class T>
class   Node
{
    public:
        Node(T here){object=here;};
        T get() { return   object; };
        void  set(T object) { this->object   =   object; };
        Node<T>* getNext() { return   nextNode; };
        void  setNext(Node<T>* nextNode) { this->nextNode   =   nextNode; };
        Node<T>* getPrev(){ return  prevNode;};
        void  setPrev(Node<T>* prevNode){this->prevNode=prevNode;};
    private:
       T object;
       Node<T>* nextNode;
       Node<T>* prevNode;
};
#endif
```

and finally the program that evokes the classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack_list.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){
Stack <char>s;
s.push("e");
cout<<s.pop();
}
```

As you can see, this is my first try at template classes. In definitions of Stack::pop() and push(T) it says, "expected type-specifier before ‘Node’"

Comment: Maybe start with something simpler?

Comment: What are the errors? What definition comes first to what, what's included where? How do you expect us to help you by just throwing the code at us?

Comment: check out the code i have updated it and tried to be clearer in my question

Comment: You should reduce the code to what is actually failing, and provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node<T>* newNode = new Node()` is inconsistent. Is `Node` a class or a class template? The first time that you mention it, you treat it as a template and instantiate it with `T`, but the second time you treat it as a class. It can't be both.

Comment: its a class template, dont know how to figure the right handside of this assignment operation, should i include Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>::Node() ?

Comment: Nope; the name of the instantiated type is `Node<T>`, and that's all you need for new: `Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>`. Yes, with C++03 you have to repeat yourself. In C++11 it's just `auto newNode = new Node<T>`.

Comment: Wow that worked! so I have to mention the type when calling a constructor .. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your method definition signatures are:

```
T Stack<T>::pop()
```

but they should be

```
template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
```

Also, since `Stack` uses `Node`, you have to include `Node.h` in `Stack.h`.

Furthermore -  in `Stack` you declared `T isEmpty();` but implemented it as `int Stack<T>::isEmpty()`. Stick to one return type (probably `bool` is more appropriate here, but `int` is also OK).

Lastly:

```
Stack <char>s;
s.push("e");
```

The template specialization is `char`, but `"e"` is a `const char*`. The correct way would be:

```
Stack <char>s;
s.push('e'); // <- note the single quotes
```

Comment: done all that but it has problems with type-specification of NODE , ,i have updated the code and pasted it above, have included Node <T> whereever a new type-node is being created